# Connected space with a given Euler characteristic

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

The question is the following:

Show that for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a connected space $X$ such that $\chi(X)=n$, where $\chi(X)$ is the Euler characteristic of $X$.

I know from the classification of compact surfaces the answer for $n\leq 2$, but I'm stuck trying to find an algorithm to construct a conected space which has Euler characteristic $n$ in general. Can you please help me?

Comment: If you have spaces $X$ and $Y$, then attaching them at a basepoint will give a space of Euler characteristic $\chi(X)+\chi(Y)-1$.

Comment: Use the fact that $\chi(X\times Y) = \chi(X)\chi(Y)$ for reasonable $X, Y$ (from, e.g., the Kunneth formula) and the result for $n \leq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The Euler characteristic of the point is $1$.

The Euler characteristic of a bouquet of $n$-circles is $1-n$,

The Euler characteristic of a bouquet $n$ of 2-spheres is $2n-1$

If you attach a circle to a bouquet of $n$ 2-spheres, the Euler characteristic is $2n-2$

Comment: Another way would be to say : If $M_n$ is a bouquet of n circles, $\chi(M) = 1-n$ so we've reached all negative numbers. Then take the cartesian product $M_n \times M_2$ so we get all positive numbers also.